# What do you call a person who makes a tender?

Tags: nouns

I am writing a document and need to find the word to describe a person who makes a tender.  Would it be "the successful tenderers...".  I expect there is an apostrophe somewhere but I'm not sure.

Comment: *bidder* is an alternative.

Comment: There is no need for any apostrophe as *tenderers* is not being used as a possessive.

Answer (score 2):

It is an awkward word, and we used to get round it (architect's office) by referring to the tender and not the tenderer, so when the results were out, we'd write something like "7 tenders were received" and "the successful tender was submitted by..." to avoid using tenderers.

Comment: I was trying to think of a work-around, but I didn't come up with that.  +1

Answer (score 0):

No, no reason for an apostrophe.  It may sound slightly awkward, but 'tenderer' is correct.

Comment: Describing it as sounding awkward was the main stumbling block for me.  Thank you.  Can I ask how I would spell the plural of 'tenderer'.

Comment: @JohnBennett Exactly as you have done.